# Contact number as unique key issue for country code or local

Tags: ios, web-services, contacts, whatsapp, mobile-application

Hello I am working on app which need mobile number as unique key, I comeup with 4 diff conditions as below:

for e.g. number is: 8888822222  that can be saved in any users contact book as:

- 8888822222
- 08888822222
- +18888822222  (with country code)
- +108888822222  (with country code)

Although above 4 are the same number but that could be different in the case of string.

So how to check and consider this 4 as same number. Can anyone help me ?

**EDIT**

My question is what should I consider in case of numbers with diff country codes and different contact number length.

Answer (score 1):

All your phone number has at least 10 digits length, So you can get last 10 digit from your contact number string and check that any unique key field contains that string.

**For eg**

```
let contactNumStr = "+18888822222"
let onlyNum = contactNumStr.substring(from:contactNumStr.index(contactNumStr.endIndex, offsetBy: -10))
//8888822222 will be store in onlyNum
```

Now you can check in your database that any unique number `contains` this `onlyNum`.

**Note that you need to check for `contains` not the exact match.**

Comment: What if any contact number is less than 10 digit ? or greater than 10 digit ?

Comment: @Esha In your question the eq you have shown is at least contains 10 digits, and from your question you are looking for mobile number and that needs to be at least 10 digits.

Comment: I accept your answer @nirav but my app is avail in diff country so need to think in that case too.

Comment: @Esha Then you can add two textField like whatsapp have done. First one for country code show country list and on selection of country put code of it and second for mobile number that will accept only 10 digits with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is gonna help you

```
if(String(phone.characters.prefix(4)) == ("0888")){
    phone = String(phone.characters.dropFirst())
}else if(String(phone.characters.prefix(3)) == ("+18")){
    phone = phone.textureName.replacingOccurrences(of: "+1", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)
}else if(String(phone.characters.prefix(3)) == ("+10")){
    phone = phone.textureName.replacingOccurrences(of: "+10", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)
}else {
    //
}
```